# Woo commerce order not showing in Order page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation, woocommerce-theming

Hi Customer received an order email confirmation.
He paid via Paypal. but the order is not showing my order tab.
Also, Order showing on Order single page i.e
example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=15920&action=edit

I tried to deactivate other plugins related to woo commerce but the issue was not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an account that has the administrator role and see if you’re able to view it then.

If it still doesn’t work, go to WooCommerce > Status > Tools and click on the button to “reset capabilities” from the list. That should restore the default capabilities of these roles. Then try accessing the orders again.

Comment: Hi I tried to reset capabilities.

Comment: But the order is still missing however I can view my order in order single page